# Ordering records using dates in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a column `move_out` that stores date in this format - m/Y e.g 02/2020. I want to order the records in that table by the `move_out` column in descending order but my solution don't seem to be working. It does not arrange the records appropriately. This is what I am doing.

```
$data = User::orderBy('move_out', 'DESC')->get();
```

How do I solve this?

The datatype for the move_out column is string.

Comment: The simple answer is store dates in the database ALWAYS as DATE or DATETIME. If you want to show dates in any other way that is a job for the presentation layer#

Comment: If you want a reliable sort you are going to have to use some SQL functions in your query to convert that string into a valid MySQL date.

Comment: `move_out` column type is varchar ?

Comment: Yes @RonakDhoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `STR_TO_DATE`

```
$data = User::orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', move_out),'%d-%m/%Y')"), 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: It does not. Not even ordering

Comment: I hope you are aware, the date is stored in this format - 02/2020. Hope it does not affect your answer?

Comment: @radioactive see screenshot

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text

Comment: @Strawberry: removed

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
$items = DB::table("users")
           ->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(move_out,'%M/%Y')"), 'DESC')
           ->get();
```